How to enable caching for the ubuntu-image bootable image generator?
I am using ubuntu-image to generate ubuntu-core images. I am following this tutorial and am using their exact command ubuntu-image snap my-model.model (albeit with an added -v verbose flag for tracing). I have attached a full log of two repeated invocations of ubuntu-image at the end of the post.
The correct output is produced, but the build process itself is very inefficient because:

There is no network or artifact caching, so each invocation of ubuntu-image downloads ~480MB of data. This puts unnecessary strain on Canonical's servers, as well as my ISP.

The wall clock execution time is ~2 minutes, but the sum of sys and user time is only ~9 seconds, meaning that majority of the run time is waiting for network traffic, i.e. downloading the required ~480MB of data.


Is there a way to enable or add caching to ubuntu-image so that it does not repeatedly download the same files from Canonical's servers over and over again?
○ → awk -v OFS=, '/wlp3s0:/ { print $10, $2 }' /proc/net/dev
108134179,3356486645


○ → time ubuntu-image snap my-model.model -v
[0] prepare_image
WARNING: proceeding to download snaps ignoring validations, this default will change in the future. For now use --validation=enforce for validations to be taken into account, pass instead --validation=ignore to preserve current behavior going forward
Fetching snapd (21759)
Fetching pc-kernel (1888)
Fetching core24 (423)
Fetching pc (178)
WARNING: the kernel for the specified UC20+ model does not carry assertion max formats information, assuming possibly incorrectly the kernel revision can use the same formats as snapd
[1] load_gadget_yaml
[2] set_artifact_names
[3] populate_rootfs_contents
[4] generate_disk_info
[5] calculate_rootfs_size
[6] populate_bootfs_contents
[7] populate_prepare_partitions
[8] make_disk
[9] generate_snap_manifest
Build successful

real    2m19.637s
user    0m4.583s
sys 0m2.546s


○ → awk -v OFS=, '/wlp3s0:/ { print $10, $2 }' /proc/net/dev
118849855,3838829806


○ → time ubuntu-image snap my-model.model -v
[0] prepare_image
WARNING: proceeding to download snaps ignoring validations, this default will change in the future. For now use --validation=enforce for validations to be taken into account, pass instead --validation=ignore to preserve current behavior going forward
Fetching snapd (21759)
Fetching pc-kernel (1888)
Fetching core24 (423)
Fetching pc (178)
WARNING: the kernel for the specified UC20+ model does not carry assertion max formats information, assuming possibly incorrectly the kernel revision can use the same formats as snapd
[1] load_gadget_yaml
[2] set_artifact_names
[3] populate_rootfs_contents
[4] generate_disk_info
[5] calculate_rootfs_size
[6] populate_bootfs_contents
[7] populate_prepare_partitions
[8] make_disk
[9] generate_snap_manifest
Build successful

real    2m34.302s
user    0m4.631s
sys 0m2.573s

○ → awk -v OFS=, '/wlp3s0:/ { print $10, $2 }' /proc/net/dev
128964754,4320308596

